# How to use GREATEST() & LEAST() functions in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle code which is like:

```
select greatest(date1, date2, date3)
from myDate
```

Is there a way to replicate this logic in SQL?

cheers

Comment: Oracle is a database that implements the SQL language (albeit in a form slightly different from the standard).  Your question doesn't make sense.  The Oracle code *is* SQL.

Comment: There are some answers to your question but they are all guessing what you actually want to achieve. Are you trying to implement the GREATEST function is MSSQL ? In which case - ask that question.

Answer (score 2):

Replicating the exact logic of `greatest()` is tricky because of the way it handles `NULL` values.  The equivalent logic would be:

```
select (case when date1 is null or date2 is null or date3 is null then null
             when date1 >= date2 and date1 >= date3 then date1
             when date2 >= date3 then date2
             else date3
        end) 
from . . .;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Azure SQL DB now supports GREATEST/LEAST.  Future SQL Server versions will as well.

[GREATEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
[LEAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a way to replace the `GREATEST` function without actually using the `GREATEST` function, then you may use `CASE` expressions instead:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN date1 > date2
         THEN
         (CASE WHEN date1 > date3 THEN date1 ELSE date3 END)
         ELSE
         (CASE WHEN date2 > date3 THEN date2 ELSE date3 END) END AS greatest
FROM dual
```